# How to use "where in" method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello Everybody i have problem with my program i need check multi number in my database but when i test it just show only one result my code :

```
/*in mt View*/
$data = array(


          'name' => 'search_id',
          'id' => 'search_id',
          'placeholder' => 'numbers_test',
          'autofocus' =>"autofocus",
          'rows' => '20'
          );

echo form_textarea($data,set_value('search_id'));

/* in my model */

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('personal_info');
$this->db->where_in('p_id', $this->input->post('search_id'));

return $this->db->get();
```

i waiting your help for this problem

Comment: can you post your query `echo $this->db->last_query();` result. Your query can help finding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting input as comma separated ids like in string `1,5,4,8` etc from `$this->input->post('search_id')` then update your code like this

```
/* in my model */

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('personal_info');
// Explode string into array to make where_in clause work
$this->db->where_in('p_id', explode(',', $this->input->post('search_id')));

return $this->db->get();
```

as [official docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) suggest you need to provide array of options in `IN` clause

Answer (score 0):

You have to **return the result** of the query. Make changes,

```
/* In my model */

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('personal_info');
$this->db->where_in('p_id', $this->input->post('search_id'));

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();   // You've to return the result of the query
```

Also as @Saqueib said in comments, try some **debugging** when in doubt,

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
```

**OR**

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($query->result_array()); exit;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on array

Comment: Thats not the right way to code. You should feed your view only with pure data (variables, arrays, objects) and thats it.

Comment: Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on null in 
this message will display now when submit numbers

Comment: I will suggest post your controller also, where u have used this model, you should check that query ran successfully before calling `result_array()` or `num_rows` on object